# Where is the US Provisional

Tags: wo2014036568a1

This PCT claims the priority date of a US Provisional application from 2012. When I looked it up on uspto.gov, I could not find an application with that title.

Did the inventors actually do a full US patent application within 12 months of their Provisional? If so, why has it not published? If not, can they still use the benefit of the Provisional filing date for their PCT application?

Answer (score 1):

WIPO has the provisional.  Go to http://patentscope.wipo.int/search/en/search.jsf  Put in just the numerals of the publication number in the search field and your record should show up.  You will find a copy of the US provisional on the "documents" tab.

The inventors can still enter this PCT into the US national stage.  It won't get published in the US until they do this entry.

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: It may be confusing, but something that isn't "published" by the USPTO can, nonetheless, be available for the public to look at. Only published applications appear at appft.uspto.gov but a provisoanl that is used as a priority document must be available for the public to look at.

Comment: George, ditto - that's useful to know about using a Provisional as a priority document.